# Specflow 3 Issues with Postman

Tags: c#, post, get, postman, specflow

I have recently started using Specflow 3. I am trying to test GET and POST requests to Postman API using xUnit. 
However, I am trying to do this from a company network which throws

> Message: System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond)
>   ---- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond
>   -------- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond

I don't get this issue when I try this from a public network.I did set the proxies in my environment variables but that didn't help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error message says it is an `AggregateException` of multiple exceptions which may be thrown by a `Task`. Please select **Debug > Options > Debugging > General** and deselect the "Enable Just My Code" option and rerun the application which will show you an actual exception.

Comment: This is a timeout message. A typical case if the endpoint to reach is not whitelisted for your IP you are trying to access from outside.

Comment: Yes the exception is thrown by a `Task`, code for which is:
 `this.GetResponse = client.GetAsync("/get?randomData").Result;`